# Node js Couch base connection error

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Below is the set of nodejs code am using for connecting to couchbase.
Code::

```
`var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var appConfig = require('./app');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(appConfig.database.couchbase.userBrand.host + ":" + appConfig.database.couchbase.userBrand.port);
//cluster.authenticate( 'username', 'password');
var bucket  = cluster.openBucket(appConfig.database.couchbase.userBrand.bucketName);
bucket.operationTimeout = 70 * 1000;
bucket.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('CONNECT ERROR:', err);
});
exports.userBrand = bucket;`
```

But am getting the below error::

```
**CONNECT ERROR: { [Error: failed to connect to bucket] code: 2 }**
```

Am very new to nodejs as well as Couchbase.
Please excuse my language.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have authentication commented out, this is why it cannot connect. You have to provide username/password to connect the Couchbase Server. Find more information in the official documentation: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/nodejs/sdk-authentication-overview.html

Comment: Thanks, @acsej
I have tried the same but once I uncomment the authenticate it was throwing "TypeError: cluster.authenticate is not a function"

Comment: make sure you are using the latest stable library

Comment: Thanks, @avsej That worked I have updated the couchbase library and commented cluster.authenticate line and it is working. 
Thanks Again :)